# Max volume of a cuboid given constraint

Tags: matrices, optimization

Find maximum volume of a cuboid for which the sum of three dimensions does not exceed $108$.

I think expression to maximize is: $\left( 108-y-z\right)yz$. From partial derivatives I got that max will be when $(x,y,z)=(36,36,36)$. How can I prove (possibly via the Hessian matrix) that this is the maximum? Or if my reasoning is wrong then please tell me what would be the correct solution.

Comment: Follows directly from the AM/GM inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The volume to maximize is $xyz$, with the variables subjected to the constraint $x+y+z = 108$. This is a constrained extrema problem that requires you to study the associated Lagrange function $L(x,y,z,t) = xyz - t(x+y+z -108)$.

To find the critical points:

$\begin {eqnarray}
yz - t &=& 0 \\
xz - t &=& 0 \\
xy - t &=& 0 \\
x+y+z &=& 108
\end {eqnarray}$

Dropping the solutions that have $xyz=0$, the only remaining one is $(36, 36, 36, 1296)$. Is this a maximum, a minimum or nothing?

In order to decide this, write the second differential of $L$:

$$\Bbb d^2 L = z \ \Bbb d x \Bbb d y + y \ \Bbb d x \Bbb d z - \Bbb d x \Bbb d  t \\
+z \ \Bbb d y \Bbb d  x + x \ \Bbb d y \Bbb d z - \Bbb d y \Bbb d t \\
+ y \ \Bbb d z \Bbb d x + x \ \Bbb d z \Bbb d y - \Bbb d z \Bbb d t \\
+ \Bbb d t \Bbb d x + \Bbb d t \Bbb d y + \Bbb d t \Bbb d z .$$

Evaluating in the critical point:

$$\Bbb d^2 L (36, 36, 36, 1296) = 36 \Bbb d x \Bbb d y + 36 \ \Bbb d x \Bbb d z - \Bbb d x \Bbb d t \\
+ 36 \ \Bbb d y \Bbb d x + 36 \ \Bbb d y \Bbb d z - \Bbb d y \Bbb d t \\
+ 36 \ \Bbb d z \Bbb d x + 36 \ \Bbb d z \Bbb d y - \Bbb d z \Bbb d t \\
+ \Bbb d t \Bbb d x + \Bbb d t \Bbb d y + \Bbb d t \Bbb d z .$$

Now, differentiate the constraint, obtaining $\Bbb d x + \Bbb d y + \Bbb d z = 0$ and replace $\Bbb d z$ in the above expression:

$$\Bbb d^2 L (36, 36, 36, 1296) = 36 \Bbb d x \Bbb d y -36 \Bbb d x ^2 -36 \Bbb d x \Bbb d y - \Bbb d x \Bbb d t \\
+ 36 \ \Bbb d y \Bbb d x - 36 \ \Bbb d y \Bbb d x - 36 \ \Bbb d y ^2 - \Bbb d y \Bbb d t \\
- 36 \Bbb d x ^2 - 36 \Bbb d y \Bbb d x - 36 \Bbb d x \Bbb d y - 36 \Bbb d y ^2 + \Bbb d x \Bbb d t + \Bbb d y \Bbb d t \\
+ \Bbb d t \Bbb d x + \Bbb d t \Bbb d y - \Bbb d t \Bbb d x - \Bbb d t \Bbb d y \\
-72 \Bbb d x ^2 - 36 \Bbb d x \Bbb d y - 36 \Bbb d y \Bbb d x - 72 \Bbb d y ^2 .$$

Put the coefficients on the last line in a $2 \times 2$ matrix $\left( \begin {array} {cc} -72 & -36 \\ -36 & -72 \end {array} \right)$. Since $-72 <0$ and the determinant $3888>0$, the point $(36,36,36)$ is a constrained maximum. The maximum volume will then be $36^3 = 46656$.